# Cannot connect to the Internet, Limited Access(Ethernet), Windows Server 2012

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, windows-server-2012, ip, local-area-network

I am using a Windows Server 2012 for my institute, due to connectivity issues I uninstalled the services AD DS, DHCP, DNS. But after the uninstall the server is unable to connect to the Internet, moreover I cannot ping the server (static ip address) from an other pc.
**N.B** :-

- Ethernet Status shows *Sent* and *Received* information.
- IPv4 config : ip add : 192.168.0.204
                       Subnet : 255.255.255.0
                       Default Gateway : 192.168.0.2
                       Primary DNS : 218.248.240.208
                       Alternate DNS :218.248.255.162
- Tried using the Google DNS 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.8.4, but does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just thought it would help others with a similar problem may be. The solution to my problem was **Resetting the router**. With research I came to know that the **router buffer holds the address of your WS2012 DNS** server **after uninstalling** also which afterward tries to point to your Domain Server but is unable due to the uninstallation of DNS service. Specially in an **un-managed switch** scenario it would also **dynamically effect your network** and cause all sorts of unpredictable problems, specially for a novice like me :)

Thanks !!!